# How do I line nice and pretty comma seperated columns in vim

Tags: vim

I have a list of columns in vim:

```
column_foo
, column_foobar
, column_really_way_to_long
, column_prefixfoo_prefixbar_really way to long
```

I want these to become padded and joined such that it looks something like this

```
, foo     ,  bar    ,  baz    ,  quz_quadazzel
, foobar  ,  moono  ,  bleh   ,  bleh
```

Is there an easy sequence of commands that I can do for this? In addition, I'd like to know how to pad a visual block to a specific amount of characters.

```
foobar
, baz
, z
, really_long_column_of_stuff
```

I.e, how can I right pad to make all of the `columns length('    , really_long_column_of_stuff')`

Comment: I'd write a function to do that and make it act on a range

Comment: When you use placeholders 'foo', 'bar', etc., make sure you keep the same placeholders in subsequent examples so it is clear how you want them to be processed. That's what placeholders are for. Right now, it seems like you want to change words as well or something, and I can't easily say how you want to transform the original expression. I'm just saying this so you can make it easier for people to help you, and thus get more answers.

Comment: lol, get real..

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux, this neat little trick will work:

```
%!column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin. [Here](http://mysite.verizon.net/astronaut/vim/align.html#Examples) are some examples of its capabilities.